# Third party chat integration with flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there any way to **integrate whatsapp** and **Instagram** etc, chat in flutter app, if any?, can someone kindly guide me

Comment: You can maybe look at this pub.dev package for whatsapp https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_open_whatsapp . For instagram I think they have their own API.

Comment: you can simple use flutter url_launcher , instead of using any other 3rd party package. Further you can see each app's api guide on how to launch that app using url_launcher and pass required parameters.